# Trouble sieving primes from a large range

Tags: c++, stack

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t,m,n;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
        int rootn=sqrt(double(n));
        bool p[10000];      //finding prime numbers from 1 to square_root(n)
        for(int j=0;j<=rootn;j++)
            p[j]=true;
        p[0]=false;
        p[1]=false;
        int i=rootn;
        while(i--)
        {
            if(p[i]==true)
            {
                int c=i;
                do
                {
                    c=c+i;
                    p[c]=false;
                }while(c+p[i]<=rootn);
            }
        };
        i=0;
        bool rangep[10000]; //used for finding prime numbers between m and n by eliminating multiple of primes in between 1 and squareroot(n)
        for(int j=0;j<=n-m+1;j++)
            rangep[j]=true;
        i=rootn;
        do
        {
            if(p[i]==true)
            {
                for(int j=m;j<=n;j++)
                {
                    if(j%i==0&&j!=i)
                        rangep[j-m]=false;
                }
            }
        }while(i--);
        i=n-m;
        do
        {
            if(rangep[i]==true)
                printf("%d\n",i+m);
        }while(i--);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Hello I'm trying to use the sieve of Eratosthenes to find prime numbers in a range between m to n where m>=1 and n<=100000000. When I give input of 1 to 10000, the result is correct. But for a wider range, the stack is overflowed even if I increase the array sizes.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?
This code is not recurrive (from my quick glance), so a stack overflow is not expected.

Comment: @Oxinabox I'm using VS2010 , but in ideone it says runtime error

Comment: This doesn't look very C++ to me, except for the headers.

Comment: @Oxinabox.: Without recurrive code a program could also get stack-overflow. First I thought the same thing. But later after checking visual studio I have got the reason. Please check my answer.(if it reuires any modfication/correction inform me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reason of getting error

**You are declaring an enormous array as a local variable.** That's why when the stack frame of main is pushed it needs so much memory that stack overflow exception is generated. Visual studio is tricky enough to analyze the code for projected run-time stack usage and generate exception when needed.

Use this compact implementation. Moreover you can have `bs` declared in the function if you want. Don't make implementations complex.

### Implementation

```
typedef long long ll;
typedef vector<int> vi;
vi primes;
bitset<100000000> bs;
void sieve(ll upperbound) {         
  _sieve_size = upperbound + 1;                   
  bs.set();                                                 
  bs[0] = bs[1] = 0;                                     
  for (ll i = 2; i <= _sieve_size; i++) 
  if (bs[i]) {  //if not marked  

    for (ll j = i * i; j <= _sieve_size; j += i) //check all the multiples 
         bs[j] = 0; // they are surely not prime :-)

    primes.push_back((int)i); // this is prime 
} }
```

call from main()   `sieve(10000);`. You have primes list in vector `primes`.

**Note:** As mentioned in comment--stackoverflow is quite unexpected error here. You are implementing sieve but it will be more efficient if you use `bistet` instead of `bool`.

Few things like if n=10^8 then sqrt(n)=10^4. And your bool array is p[10000]. So there is a chance of accessing array out of bound.

Comment: your solution is great but i am unable to understand why increasing the array size in my case doesn't work . Is that the way boolean arrays are?

Comment: @user4684729 Bool is a byte. Your array is defined local to a function so it is on the stack. Stack is typically 1 MiB, so 1000000 elements in a bool is about as big as you can go (always a bunch of overhead chewing up some of the RAM). The bitset, and the vector used by the other answer are on the stack, but they contain dynamically allocated data and can be sized up to the storage limits that your computer has or the OS will give. In addition, they are arrays of individually accessible bits so you can get 8 elements to a byte.

Comment: @user4581301 can you give me some link so I can learn further, as  I am still confused

Comment: @user4684729.: The above code is uses space more efficiently. As in a byte you can place 8 bits and we are basically using those bits to determine the whether an element is prime or not. `hey! I have found the error` check my answer..

Comment: @coderredoc Ah ofcourse. When the allocated memory is local the the function, then is it allocated onto the stack, not the heap. If it was on the heap we would get a memory error, but because it is on the stack we get a stackoverflow. \

Comment: “You are declaring an enormous array as a local variable.”  I don’t see how that, by itself, can be the root cause of the problem.  The array dimensionality is constant, and the OP says that the program works for `n`≤10000, so it looks like the array instantiation succeeds.

Comment: @G-Man.: Yes OP said that when he increased the size then it caused problem. I have checked it myself in Visual Studio. For small array size it is not a problem. Just run the above code in visual c++ then increase the array size and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

A simple and more readable implementation

```
void Sieve(int n) {
    int sqrtn = (int)sqrt((double)n);
    std::vector<bool> sieve(n + 1, false);
    for (int m = 2; m <= sqrtn; ++m) {
        if (!sieve[m]) {
            cout << m << " ";
            for (int k = m * m; k <= n; k += m)
                sieve[k] = true;
        }
    }
    for (int m = sqrtn; m <= n; ++m)
        if (!sieve[m])
            cout << m << " ";
}
```

Comment: can you tell me why increasing my array size doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers,
saying that you should basically just start over. 
Do you even care why your code doesn’t work?  (You didn’t actually ask.)

I’m not sure that the problem in your code
has been identified accurately yet. 
First of all, I’ll add this comment to help set the context:

```
// For any int aardvark;
// p[aardvark] = false   means that aardvark is composite (i.e., not prime).
// p[aardvark] = true    means that aardvark might be prime, or maybe we just don’t know yet.
```

Now let me draw your attention to this code:

```
        int i=rootn;
        while(i--)
        {
            if(p[i]==true)
            {
                int c=i;
                do
                {
                    c=c+i;
                    p[c]=false;
                }while(c+p[i]<=rootn);
            }
        };
```

You *say* that `n`≤100000000 (although your code doesn’t check that), so,
presumably, `rootn`≤10000, which is the dimensionality (size) of `p[]`. 
The above code is saying that, for every integer `i`
(no matter whether it’s prime or composite),
2×`i`, 3×`i`, 4×`i`, etc., are, by definition, composite. 
So, for `c` equal to 2×`i`, 3×`i`, 4×`i`, …,
we set `p[c]=false` because we know that `c` is composite.

But look closely at the code. 
It sets `c=c+i` and says `p[c]=false`
*before* checking whether `c` is still in range
to be a valid index into `p[]`. 
Now, if `n`≤25000000, then `rootn`≤5000. 
If `i`≤ `rootn`, then `i`≤5000, and, as long as `c`≤5000, then `c+i`≤10000. 
But, if `n`>25000000, then `rootn`>5000,<sup>†</sup>
and the sequence `i=rootn;`, `c=i;`, `c=c+i;`
can set `c` to a value greater than 10000. 
And then you use that value to index into `p[]`. 
That’s probably where the stack overflow occurs.

Oh, BTW; you  don’t need to say `if(p[i]==true)`; `if(p[i])` is good enough.

To add insult to injury, there’s a second error in the same block:
`while(c+p[i]<=rootn)`. 
`c` and `i` are `int`<sub>s</sub>,
and `p` is an array of `bool`<sub>s</sub>, so `p[i]` is a `bool` —
and yet you are adding `c + p[i]`. 
We know from the `if` that `p[i]` is `true`,
which is numerically equal to `1` —
so your loop termination condition is `while (c+1<=rootn)`;
i.e., while `c`≤`rootn-1`. 
I think you meant to say `while(c+i<=rootn)`.

Oh, also, why do you have executable code
immediately after an unconditional `return` statement? 
The `system("PAUSE");` statement cannot possibly be reached.

(I’m not saying that those are the only errors;
they are just what jumped out at me.)
______________
<sup>†</sup> OK, splitting hairs, `n` has to be ≥ 25010001
(i.e., 5001<sup>2</sup>) before `rootn`>5000.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for reading my ugly code . I did ask @coderredoc why increasing my array size hadn't worked and from what you stated even if I used another data structure in my code I would've gotten the error . I'll think more before posting a question here and hopefully relearn c++ .